# How can I mimic 3D rotation of an object represented by a set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 24 images taken under different angles which represent 3D model of an object.
I want to add 180* degrees rotation functionality to my website like in [example](http://andrushko.net/demo/demo.html) 
The object should be "rotated" using a scroller, like shown in example.
Also, I have to add hotspots to some images.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Open your Notepad and write :`<html>` ... :)

Comment: Have a look at CSS' [transform3d()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate3d()) and [Intro to CSS 3D transforms](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/)

Comment: I don't want to move my element. All I need to do is to switch between different images (divs) as I move the scroller. This will create 3d rotation effect since all the images are taken under different angles with a small angle step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have images from lots of angles, it sounds like you can do this in jQuery without 3D CSS transforms.

Load up all the images and give them different `id`'s:

```
<div id="3dview">
  <img src="..." id="angle1" style="display:block;" /> <!-- display this first -->
  <img src="..." id="angle2" />

  <img src="..." id="angle24" />
</div>
```

Use the CSS declaration `position: absolute` (along with `top` and `left`) to ensure they are all displayed on top of each other. Ensure that they are hidden (ie `display:none`) by default.  You can show just one image to display the initial angle.

```
#3dview img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Then, in JavaScript, you can wire up a [slider control, perhaps from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), and show one particular `<img />` element (whilst keeping all the others hidden).  You'd need to listen to events from the control, e.g.:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) { /* code here */} );
```

I'd recommend starting with just two buttons though, "rotate left by 1 step" and "rotate right by 1 step". This would look for the only `img:visible`, hide it, select its next/previous sibling and then show that.

```
// code to display the next image (ie 'rotate' by one step)
$("#3dview img:visible").hide().next().show()
```

You might need to check if the user is on the first or last views and change the behaviour, either looping round or stopping the rotation.  You could try just chaining the selector `:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)` above.

Comment: Let me know if some example jQuery would help!

Comment: Could you please provide some jQuery example as well? I'm using jScrollPane now to scroll a list of these images, but images should toggle instead of scrolling

Comment: Also, will the same approach work if I have divs, not images?

Comment: jScrollPane provides some quite different functionality; it's less suited to triggering javascript functions.  You can definitely use divs instead of images; just make sure they're all stacked on top of each other with CSS and that you're selecting them correctly with jQuery!

Comment: My pleasure, your question was concise and clear; a rare surprise among unanswered StackOverflow questions!  Hopefully within your 24 `div`s you can set up your hotspots using small absolutely positioned elements or maybe even an [image-map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)